# 'It's great fun to play with somebody.' vs 'It's great fun playing with somebody.'

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I wonder if anyone here can help: 'It's great fun to play with him' and 'It's great fun playing with him'. Are they both correct? I feel the second one sounds more natural, but how about the first one?
Many thanks!

Comment: What do mean by "playing" here?

Answer (score 0):

**They are both correct.**

Whether one is more 'natural' than the other may depend on the context.

Consider this (grammatically correct) lyric from [a very popular 90's song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTWKbfoikeg):

> *It's fun **to lose** and **to pretend***.

The singer uses the infinitive here because the emphasized syllables fit well with the tune.

However, this is also correct:

> *It's fun **losing** and **pretending***.

Hope this helps!